# How to select an element inside a component

Tags: reactjs

Hi i'm trying to apply a style on my

element after clicking ont my checkbox and i'm note entirely sure on how to select the element

i tried to use ref , and id but without sucess

{this.props.articles.map(el => (

```
                <li className="list-group-item" id={el.id}>
                    {el.title}
                <button  type="button" className="btn  btn-lg-4 buttonContainer buttonRight" id={el.id} onClick={this.handleDelete}>
                X
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox"  className="inputLeft list-group-item" id={el.id} onClick={this.handleChecking}/>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>


    handleChecking(el){

        if (el.target.checked) {
        console.log('true');
        var idLi = el.target.id;
        console.log("id =" + idLi);
        this.ref.
        //console.log(this.ref.value(idLi));

        }
```

when the check-box is checked i'd like to apply the style  text-decoration: line-through on the

element with the same id

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
this.state = {
     elementClicked: false, 
     elementId : 0
}
const {elementClicked, elementId} = this.state;
 <ul>
{this.props.articles.map(el => (

                <li className="list-group-item" {elementClicked && elementId === el.id ? /*set your style*/ : /*remove style*/} {id={el.id}>
                    {el.title}
                <button  type="button" className="btn  btn-lg-4 buttonContainer buttonRight" id={el.id} onClick={this.handleDelete}>
                X
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox"  className="inputLeft list-group-item" id={el.id} onChange={() => this.handleChecking(el.id)}/>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>


    handleChecking(elementID){
  // grab element id 
const {elementClicked, elementId} = this.state;
this.setState({  
    elementClicked: !elementClicked,
    elementId
})
        if (el.target.checked) {
        console.log('true');
        var idLi = el.target.id;
        console.log("id =" + idLi);
        this.ref.
        //console.log(this.ref.value(idLi));

        }
```

Comment: The main issue is still to select the <li> element to change it's style

Comment: Oh I see, so you need to create a state variable to set when element is checked or clicked, that way you know the id of the element is when you set state, I'll edit the post.